# upgrade the project from ef4.3 to ef5

Tags: entity-framework

I have a project which is using EF4.3, is it possible to upgrade it to EF5? This is, so I can use the new features. My IDE is VS2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nuget the new package, it should replace your existing .dlls.  See [the Entity Framework nuget package site](http://nuget.org/packages/entityframework).

In package manager console enter:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```